# segfault from PCL SHOTEstimationOMP

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a seg fault problem. I tried to run it with valgrind but I can't figure what caused the problem from the [results](http://pastebin.com/h1Z6WWsZ). I also tried gdb but the results aren't much better. I don't see where the problem came from.

Some context for seg fault

global:

```
pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::Ptr modelPtr (new pcl::PointCloud<PointType> ());
pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::Ptr model_keypoints (new pcl::PointCloud<PointType> ());
```

in main:

```
  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile (model_filename_, *modelPtr) < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "pcl::io::loadPCDFile error" << std::endl;
    return (-1);
  }
```

in callback function:

```
  pcl::NormalEstimationOMP<PointType, NormalType> norm_est;
  norm_est.setKSearch (10);
  norm_est.setInputCloud (modelPtr);
  norm_est.compute (*model_normals);
  
  pcl::copyPointCloud (*modelPtr, sampled_indices.points, *model_keypoints);
  
  pcl::SHOTEstimationOMP<PointType, NormalType, DescriptorType> descr_est;
  descr_est.setRadiusSearch (descr_rad_);
  descr_est.setInputCloud (model_keypoints); 
  descr_est.setInputNormals (model_normals); 
  descr_est.setSearchSurface (modelPtr);
  descr_est.compute (*model_descriptors); //segfault
```

Any ideas what could be the cause of this problem?

Edit: gdb backtrace results are [here](http://pastebin.com/3KYv8DSj).

Edit2: I also get this warning from building this node

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/strstream:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkIOStream.h:112,
                 from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkSystemIncludes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkIndent.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkObjectBase.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkSmartPointerBase.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkSmartPointer.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/point_cloud_geometry_handlers.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/point_cloud_handlers.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/common/actor_map.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h:47,
                 from /home/ros-user/catkin_ws/src/kinect_pr2/src/subscriber.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/backward_warning.h:33:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
```

But line 15 is `#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>` so it will be probably unrelated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202006/segfault-from-pcl-shotestimationomp/) by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2015-01-29**:
A `gdb` trace would be nice, are you using `c++11` ? Maybe you are facing [this issue](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/619).

**Comment by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on 2015-01-29**:
Added gdb backtrace. I haven't specified standard.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2015-01-29**:
best place to ask pcl questions would be its forum
http://www.pcl-users.org/
Here is a possible solution
http://smrpn.blogspot.sg/2014/02/kdtree-headers-in-pcl.html

**Comment by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on 2015-01-29**:
My includes were fine... I asked on the forum you suggested. Thx for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out it was neither PCL nor ROS problem. There was something broken in my OS.

---

Originally posted by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) with karma: 32 on 2015-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0